# Backbone Collection fetching throwing id error

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to figure out Backbone.js and am going through the PeepeCode backbone.js basics video.

When I try and fetch the collection in the Chrome's Javascript console, it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in [{
```

here is my json:

```
[{
   "id" : "1",
   "title": "Bound - Zen Bound Ingame Music",
   "artist": "Ghost Monkey"
 },
 {
   "id": "2",
   "title": "Where the Earth Meets the Sky",
   "artist": "Tom Heasley"
}]
```

here is my Collection code:

```
window.Albums = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model : Album,

    url: '/services/AlbumsService'

});
```

Any ideas? Not sure why this is happening. I have an id field in the json..so I'm puzzled. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the collection initialise correctly if you load it's models directly, i.e. without fetch(): `var albums = new window.Albums(); albums.reset([{"id":"1", ...}]);`?  First guess I'd say the JSON is not being sent correctly by the server.

Comment: So when you do an Albums.fetch() the server is sending back that JSON in the response? Because it looks pretty clean. Have you fiddled with the sync function or is it straight out of the box? What function are you running to search for a model id? collections.get(id) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your model Album is visible to your collection? and does it inherits from Backbone.Model.extend?